# iOS CFBundleVersion to float

Tags: ios, nsstring, floating-point, version

Is there a way to change the CFBundleVersion variable (an NSString)  to an float.

My version currently is '1.0.2', but when i parse the floatValue from it, it will return 1.00000.

How to parse it so i will get this value: 1.02000

Thanks.

Comment: I want to know if my app was updated since the last time it was started.

Comment: As you don't downgrade, a check of equality is often good enough for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. There are two decimal points, and no unambiguous way to represent that as a float. You might roll your own code to convert it to *something*, but basically the approach as such is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
    CGFloat versionNumber;

    NSArray *versionItems = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    if (versionItems.count == 3)
    {
        NSInteger major = [[versionItems objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
        NSInteger minor = [[versionItems objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
        NSInteger bug = [[versionItems objectAtIndex:2] integerValue];

        versionNumber = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.%ld%ld",(long)major,(long)minor,(long)bug] floatValue];
    }
    else
    {
        versionNumber = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"] floatValue];
    }
```